# Can't use addslashes on PHP SQL Server ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, addslashes

**EDIT** I'm using MS SQL, I query to MySQL then Insert it to MS SQL

I wrote a script that will query a data from a databse and upload it to another database. So the script is like this

```
    $id                       = $row["id"];
    $title                    = $row["title"];
    $firstname                = safe($row["firstname"]);
    $surname                  = safe($row["surname"]);
    $dob                      = $row["dob"];
    $phone                    = $row["phone"];
    $addr1                    = safe($row["addr1"]);
    $addr2                    = $row["addr2"];
    $towncity                 = $row["towncity"];
    $postcode                 = $row["postcode"];
    $user_platform            = $row["user_platform"];
    $user_browser             = $row["user_browser"];
    $user_browser_ver         = $row["user_browser_ver"];
    $user_ip                  = $row["user_ip"];
    $terms                    = $row["terms"];
    $privacy_policy           = $row["privacy_policy"];
    $column_header            = $row["column_header"];
    $column_header_response   = safe($row["column_header_response"]);
    $column_header_response_2 = safe($row["column_header_response_2"]);
    $column_header_response_3 = safe($row["column_header_response_3"]);
    $column_header_response_4 = safe($row["column_header_response_4"]);
    $column_header_response_5 = safe($row["column_header_response_5"]);
    $filename                 = $row["filename"];
    $cpl                      = $row["cpl"];
    $rejected                 = $row["rejected"];
    $reject_reason            = $row["reject_reason"];
    $email                    = $row["email"];
    $created_at               = $row["created_at"];
    $updated_at               = $row["updated_at"];

$values = "
            $id,
            '$title',
            '$firstname',
            '$surname',
            '$dob',
            '$phone',
            '$addr1',
            '$addr2',
            '$towncity',
            '$postcode',
             $age,
            '$user_platform',
            '$user_browser',
            '$user_browser_ver',
            '$user_ip',
            '$terms',
            '$privacy_policy',
            '$column_header',
            '$column_header_response',
            '$column_header_response_2',
            '$column_header_response_3',
            '$column_header_response_4',
            '$column_header_response_5',
            '$filename',
            '$cpl',
            '$rejected',
            '$reject_reason',
            '$email',
            '$created_at',
            '$updated_at'
            ";

 function safe($value){ 
   return addslashes($value); 
}
```

Then this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO forms VALUES(".$values.");";
```

Then I have some error

```
SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Neill'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect
```

which is likely to be the unescapped string but I already have it. When I tried to echo the query:

```
INSERT INTO forms VALUES( 122, 'Miss', 'John', 'O\'Neill', '1973-08-16', '+447939161234', '31w Red Square', '', 'Johnstone', 'PA5 8AD', 44, '', '', '', '', '', '', 'washing_machine', '5yrs and above', 'zanussi', '', '', '', '', '0.17', '', '', 'john.oneill@gmail.net', '2015-08-04', '2015-08-04' );
```

Looks like the O'Nielll is not escapped or there's a problem with my quotes? How to fix this? thanks

Comment: I think SQL Server uses a quote `'` to escape a quote `''`

Comment: I forgot that I'm uploading to SQL Server not MySQL thanks for mentioning, trying to fix it now